# Problems when trying to connect to internet on Kali through bridged adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kali-linux, bridged

I just installed Kali through a Virtualbox, and if I leave the network settings to 'NAT', it's all good. However, when I switch it to bridged adapter (which is recommended in nearly every tutorial/documentation I've read) I can't get it to work.

I've already tried the following:

Go to Network manager and change 'managed' to true and then 
restart the network manager

I've read various questions from other people running in to the same problem, and 99% of the time they either solve it by setting the network mode to NAT and/or by repeating the steps I previously mentioned.

Can it be that I overlooked the fact that bridged is for when using WiFi? Because whenever I unplug my host machine's internet cable, I can connect through the Internet on Kali.

Is there any way to get Kali functioning through a bridged adapter?

Answer (score 1):

To get your Kali functioning through a bridged adapter in VirtualBox (while wired): Either enable promiscous mode on the VirtualBox NIC, or configure a static IP within Kali.

Bridged mode in VirtualBox has a completely different behavior over wireless than wired.  In wireless, it is assumed that the adapter is not capable of promiscous mode, so VirtualBox will intercept and inject data into ethernet packets sent/received by the host NIC (namely source and destination MACs).